# Get Last executed query which was ran inside controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

How do I get the last running query which was ran inside a controller(not in a Model) in the Cakephp application? I am adding this functionality to an existing system that has a few running queries inside the Controller, and I was wondering, would it pull out the data? For example, the query is:

```
$this->Main->query("select a from b");
```

The query is not inside a model, which is making it a little bit hard, but is it possible for me to pull it out? Also, I am running a MSSQL Database if that helps.

Comment: You _are_ calling a query on a model object - the way to get the query log is the same. Why you wouldn't create a model method and call it isn't clear (i.e. why you're taking some - sounds like - badly architectured code and adding to it/making it worse)